# How bitbucket attach the bug # to a commit's message

Tags: java, git, github, bitbucket

Could any one answer to my question that I am using bitBucket, and I have seen it's feature that when we commit and mention ticket # in message.it associate ticket # catch that commit and associate to it.
How does it works is that implemented using **server Hooks** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referencing a BitBucket issue, you can use the commands inside your commit message and you shouldn't have to add any hooks. For example:

`First step in refactor. See #5` - to reference the commit in issue #5

`Remove the buggy XYZ module, replace with ABC. Closes #3` - to reference the commit in issue #3 and close it

See the [Atlassian BitBucket Documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/mark-up-comments-issues-and-commit-messages-321859781.html) for details.

If you're referencing a JIRA ticket, you can register the commit in the sidebar by simply using the ticket number anywhere in the commit message, eg: `A commit message for ABC-1234`. You can do comments eg: `A commit message. ABC-1234 #comment Some specific message to add to the ticket as a comment`.

For JIRA and other Atlassian services you do have to hook your repository to those systems, do that through the repository's Settings section.

See the [JIRA Smart Commit Messages documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/processing-jira-software-issues-with-smart-commit-messages-298979931.html) for details.

Comment: How does it works is that implemented using server Hooks ?

Comment: can u please share any useful link of this so i can understand.

Comment: @JohnnyMartin I added links to the documentation from Atlassian